# In Harry Potter, does the Daily Prophet report news internationally?

Tags: harry-potter

Does the Daily Prophet report news about what happens in other countries? How do the Wizards in Britain know about what happens in the Wizarding world of other countries?

Comment: http://img14.deviantart.net/9b76/i/2012/274/9/4/daily_prophets_by_jhadha-d5gamig.jpg

Comment: @Valorum All of those appear to be UK only stories. On the other hand we probably only see the pages relating to the story and most international news would be pushed off the main pages if Voldermort was around.

Comment: Does international quidditch count?

Answer (score 2):

## Yes (at least regarding Quidditch)

The sports column of the Daily Prophet would cover international Quidditch (or at least during the World Cup season.)

You can read a collection of their articles from the 2014 cup [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gixH.jpg)<sup>1</sup>, written by sports correspondent Ginny Potter.

To quote a random passage:

> Ivorian Chaser Elodie Dembélé, aged only 18, scored seven of **Ivory Coast**'s ten goals. **Norwegian** Seeker Sigrid Kristoffersen out-raced her counterpart Sylvian Boigny to take the Snitch in the 128th minute.
> <sub>NORWAY VERSUS IVORY COAST, Sunday Prophet, April 13th 2014</sub>

---

<sup>1. Screenshots from the old Pottermore. These were some of the stuff lost when Pottermore "upgraded" their website,</sup>